# Array of custom object in Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, class, object

let's say we have a module called students. We explore it. In other js file, We declare an array of students object. as

`var studentsArray =[];`

and later on for loop each elements to add student object, as -

`for(var i=1; i< 15; i++){
  studentsArray[i]= new students;
}`

Are there any better way to handle array of custom object in Node.js?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you should probably use `var i = 0` as in JS and most other C-style languages array index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

One way or the other you need to iterate.

The two ways I can think to do it are:

1. The way you did it.
2. Use array.push

**Yours**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  studentsArray[i] = new Student(...);
}
```

**Using push**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  studentsArray.push(new Student(...));
}
```

You could try other loop constructs like a while or do/while, but those are cosmetic differences.  In terms of adding to the array, this is what you have.